# Compare values between different rows in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to **pandas** and I'm trying to compare values between rows without luck.
I want to find the `RSI` **difference** between the row where `DOJI` is `100` and **next one**.
In this case,  `52.157595` - `45.430342`.
What should I do for that?
I've played a bit with `query()` but I've no idea of what I'm doing...

```
                    Close   RSI       MOM   MACD        HAM  HMAN DOJI
20161125  10:13:00  69.87  52.157595 -0.21  0.011241    0     0   100
20161125  10:14:00  69.77  45.430342 -0.24  0.003785    0     0     0
20161125  10:15:00  69.77  45.430342 -0.10 -0.002099    0     0     0
20161125  10:16:00  69.83  49.924669 -0.02 -0.001899    0     0     0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `diff` with `loc`

```
df.RSI.diff(-1).loc[df.DOJI.eq(100)]

20161125  10:13:00    6.727253
Name: RSI, dtype: float64
```

---

***explanation***
Hopefully `diff` is self explanatory.  However, the `-1` aligns the index with the current row and not the next one.  That means if I mask it with the boolean series of when `DOJI` is `100` then I have my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd locate the rows and do manipulation in `numpy`

```
this_row = np.append((df.DOJI.values == 100)[:-1], False)
next_row = np.roll(this_row, 1)

rsi = df.RSI.values

pd.Series(rsi[this_row] - rsi[next_row],
          df.index.values[this_row], name='RSI')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `shift` in a similar way to `diff`

```
(df['RSI'] - df['RSI'].shift(-1))[df['DOJI'] == 100]
```